# add images from popup to parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I written a simple image editor PHP script, users can add images from galleries to editor area and merge all finally.

now my problem is:

galleries open as popup and editor area is parent page, i need a javascript or jquery code when a user clicked on a item in popup page, image added to parent page in specific div.

here is destination div code:

```
        <div id="objects">
            <div class="obj_item"><img id="obj_1" class="ui-widget-content" src="elements/1.png" /></div>
            <div class="obj_item"><img id="obj_2" class="ui-widget-content" src="elements/2.png" /></div>
        </div>
```

please help me,
thanks

Comment: no one uses pop-ups anymore, I hope you have a [modal dialog](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) and not a popup...

Comment: thank you @balexandre I convert popup code to modal dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target the parent using `window.opener`

```
$('#objects', window.opener).append('image code');
```